# Guest Network and NAS

Tags: networking, router, routing, nas, subnet

I am trying to setup a network where I can achieve several things.  I might be overthinking this, but here is how I envision it working:

1. I am willing to use 2 or 3 routers
2. I want a network or subnet that contains all my pc's, network printer, etc. and connects to the internet.
3. I would like another subnet that has a NAS.  I would like my pc's and devices to be able to reach this NAS.
4. I would like a subnet (WiFi) that my friend who lives next door can access.  In this subnet, I would like my friend to be able to access the NAS, but not use my internet and not be able to reach my pc's and devices.

I was thinking using a star topology with a 'main router' connected to my DSL modem and connected to 2 "children routers" on its LAN ports and connecting to their WAN ports (subnet 1).  Use one of the "children routers" to create a second subnet that contains all my devices (subnet 2).  Then use the other "child routers" to create another subnet with the NAS hardwired to one of its LAN ports and use its wireless for my friend to access it (subnet 3).  Leave out default gateway information and NAT information on the router creating subnet 3 so that it cannot connect to the internet.  Then use static routes to find the subnets I want talking.  Has anyone does this already?  Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

A. If the NAS is capable just give them VPN access to it, but not pass through to any other address than localhost(NAS but nothing else)

B. VLANs. Dont setup three routers, get one good one that allows VLANS.

```
VLAN 10 - Private LAN
VLAN 20 - Shared Space
VLAN 30 - Public
```

Access controls to allow 10 to access 20 and 30 to access 20, but not 30 access 10.